# We're Chatting!

Tags: discussion

Congrats on hitting minor milestone: **two people in TRex chat at the same time**.

- [Join along](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7585/tridion).
- Topic: "[Stuff](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8190300#8190300)"

**Discuss**:

1. Think we'll benefit from community chat?
2. What would you like to see it used for and how might you help?

Comment: I read at first "cheating" :D

Comment: Only the TRex admins know who's cheating. ;-)